# I compile 'myclass.java' with javac and no errors, however when I run 'myclass.class' with java it says NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java

How is it not found if it was able to find it to run itself?? Here is the code:

```
class myclass{

   int x = 10;

   int Voo(int x){
      x += 4;
      return x;

   }

   int VooUp(int x){
      x+= 7;
      return 7; 
   }


   public static void main(String[] args){

      myclass obj = new myclass();

      System.out.println( obj.Voo(obj.x) ); 
      System.out.println( obj.x );


   }

}
```

java myclass.class fails saying myclass definition is not found... :(

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the ".class" extension when specifying the class to run.

You may need a classpath argument as well; e.g.

```
java -cp . myclass
```

Comment: Current directory should be the default classpath, but +1 for mentioning it nonetheless.

Comment: @jmccarthy Good point, as I understand it the default classpath can be overriden by the CLASSPATH environment variable so I was advocating specifying the default classpath for safety and completeness.

Answer (score 2):

The command line you need is:

```
java -cp . myclass
```